# 'list' object is not callable with silhouette_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k).fit(df)
preds = kmeans.fit_predict(df)
silhouette_score.append(silhouette_score(df, preds, metric = 'euclidean'))
```

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

I am not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably created a list variable somewhere in your code named `silhouette_score`, which you now try to append. This way, you have overwritten the existing scikit-learn method [`silhouette_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html), hence your script cannot find it now, considers `silhouette_score` a list, and when trying to execute

```
silhouette_score(df, preds, metric = 'euclidean')
```

throws an error as expected, because lists are indeed not callable.

You should **never** create variables with names identical to these of existing functions and methods. Change the name of your `silhouette_score` variable to something else, reset & rerun your script, and you should be fine.